# Need to link item in list A to specific item in list B

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-item

I need to link to a specific item on a list.

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010

The issue I am having:

I have two lists, both are filled with items. The items in list A have a link within them that need to be linked to specific items in list B. The items in list A are "issues" that all have a unique ID numbers which correspond to a "resolution" item in list B.

How do I link an item in list A to a specific item in list B?

Comment: Please add some more information about your problem.  The title says "from a modal dialog" -- so you have some modal dialog open and you need a link to a specific item in the modal dialog?  Do you want to link to the item's display form?  Edit form?  How is the modal dialog opened?  Etc., etc.  Please add more detail.

Comment: I added more info. It was the end of the day at work and I was at my wits end and couldn't think how to properly word the question. After a good nights sleep I believe I've done a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a link between items in one list to items in a different list by using a **lookup column**.

In this case, you would create the lookup column on List A, and have it "look up" List B.

You don't even need SP Designer to do it, you can do it right through the UI.

There are numerous resources available online with instructions on how to create lookup columns, [here is one](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632).  [Here is another (short video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShLH0mBcA54).

Comment: The video did not exactly explain what I needed in this case.

When I view an item in list A, there is a link to a specific item in list B. However, when I click that link it doesn't go to the right item in list B, it takes me to the first item which isn't the correct one. How do I get the link in list A to take me to the correct item in list B.

When in the code for list A,, there is an onclick for a link, however it just takes to the first item in list B, is there a way to change that url to go to a specific item in list B?

Comment: I can't really answer that, because I don't know how the link URL in the item in list A is generated.  Do you know how that link is generated?

Comment: It's just a link to the custom display form.

Comment: You are saying it's a custom display form, so I don't know how the item ID is getting passed to it, but for the OOB display form, the ID of the item to show is passed as a query string parameter.  If you look at something in the OOB display form, and look at the URL, you should see something like `DispForm.aspx?ID=` and then a number.  That number is the ID of the item to show.  So to get the display form to show different items, you have to pass it different ID numbers.  If your link is always showing the same item, it might be always getting assigned the same ID. [cont.]

Comment: That's why I'm asking how the link is getting built -- when the link is built, it should be built with the ID of the item to link to in list B, which I'm guessing should be different for every item in list A.  However, again, you are saying it's a custom form, so I don't know exactly how that information is getting passed to the form.

Comment: The URL does look like that, however, there is no number after ID=. I'm not sure what you mean by "how the link is getting built", this project was given to me and the person who created it is no longer here. 
Here's the statement for the URL if it helps any:
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('URL'); return false;">

Comment: What I mean by "how the link is getting built" is this: In order for the link to open the right item, you need to know the ID of the item in list B to open.  So, when you are opening the form for an item in list A, somehow the form needs to know the corresponding item ID in list B to put in the link.  Maybe this is happening server side in C# code as the form page is being built. Maybe it is happening in Javascript on the client side after the form loads.  Either way, the link has to reference an ID of an item in list B, that should be dictated by the particular item in list A. [contd.]

Comment: So the link, as it stands on its own, is incomplete, until the particular item from list A is loaded into the form, and somewhere there is an indication of the correct item ID to put in the URL of the link at the `ID=` spot.  This has to happen dynamically, or else you will always load the same item from list B.  Since it is happening dynamically, the full link is "being built".

Comment: So there's no communication between list A and list B? How do I fix this?

Comment: Without seeing all of the code involved in the custom form for list A, I can't really say.  I can only assume that the previous dev had a plan for how to figure out which item in list B each item in list A was linked to. Are there no other devs at your company you can ask for help?  In any case, that's why I suggested adding a Lookup column - that way, when you create (or edit) an item in list A, you can specify "this item should be linked to this exact item in list B", and the lookup column in list A will display as a hyperlink to the display form for the item in list B.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I will try adding a lookup column and see if that solves the issue. :D